# UIScrollView - thumbnail view of UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

In a `UIViewController`, I have a `UIScrollView` that takes half of the screen. This `UIScrollView` contains a collection of `UIView`.

In this `UIViewController`, I registered a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` which works fine. However, I don't want the `UIScrollView` to be able to recognize the swipe, is there a way to do this? For example, if I swipe within any location in this `UIViewController` but not within the `UIScrollView` which is embedded within it, it should recognize the swipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subclass `UIScrollview` say "MyScrollView" and override touchesBegin,Moved and Ended methods and leave them empty.

use `MyScrollView` as the class for your scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line if it works :

```
[self.view setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```